# Suggestions for improvements to genetic algorithms for matching

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to use GAs for the following search problem:

There is a set of 30 vectors, each with 1500 elements:

A[30x1500]

And there is a library of 2000 vectors, each with 1500 elements

B[2000 x 1500]

I try to find the set of (30) vectors in B that match closest to the vectors in A.

I am using GAs (basic selection->crossover->mutation) and am getting reasonably good results, but the code is really slow. I am using a correlation function as the fitness and this might be the bottleneck, though the number of iterations is certainly a bottleneck too (about 500 iterations to get a 95 % correlation).

Has anyone used GAs for similar problems? Or GAs extensively...Are there any common tips I can use to improve speed and/or convergence?

Thank you!

P.S: My program is written in R.

Comment: If you are just looking for the vectors in B with the highest correlation with the vectors in A,
genetic algorithms are overkill: `apply( cor(A,B), 1, which.max )` directly gives you the result.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but package `data.table` speeds up search operations in large data frame like objects by a factor of about 100 (or so the authors at least claim). You can find the package with quite comprehensive documentation on CRAN: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a rather trivial computation.  You can just compute it using Euclidean distance and distribute the calculations.  On a multicore machine you should have the answer in no time.

GA is absolutely not the way to go for this problem.